# How can i send data over network and make a terminal with pygame?

Tags: python, sockets, pygame

So I try to make a drone controller and for now I want to make it work on keyboard only and the best way to do that is PyGame, but when I try to make the loop from PyGame, it just freezes.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
import threading
import socket
import pygame
pygame.init()

green = (0, 255, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)

font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)

win = pygame.display.set_mode((900,500))

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("127.0.0.1", 55555))

pygame.init()

def send_data(data):
    if data == True:
        client.send(f"{data}1".encode('utf-8'))
    elif data == False:
        client.send(f"{data}0".encode('utf-8'))

def receive():
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            print(message)
        except:
            print("An error occured!")
            client.close()
            exit()

def write():
    running = True
    fata = False
    spate = False
    stanga = False
    dreapta = False
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    fata = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    spate = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    stanga = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    dreapta = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    fata = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    spate = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    stanga = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    dreapta = False

        win.fill(black)

        textw = font.render("fata:", True, green)
        textRect = textw.get_rect(center=(40, 20))
        win.blit(textw, textRect)

        textw = font.render(str(fata), True, green)
        textRect = textw.get_rect(center=(125, 20))
        win.blit(textw, textRect)

        texts = font.render("spate:", True, green)
        textRect = texts.get_rect(center=(55, 50))
        win.blit(texts, textRect)

        texts = font.render(str(spate), True, green)
        textRect = texts.get_rect(center=(150, 50))
        win.blit(texts, textRect)

        texta = font.render("stanga:", True, green)
        textRect = texta.get_rect(center=(65, 80))
        win.blit(texta, textRect)

        texta = font.render(str(stanga), True, green)
        textRect = texta.get_rect(center=(170, 80))
        win.blit(texta, textRect)

        textd = font.render("dreapta:", True, green)
        textRect = textd.get_rect(center=(70, 110))
        win.blit(textd, textRect)

        textd = font.render(str(dreapta), True, green)
        textRect = textd.get_rect(center=(180, 110))
        win.blit(textd, textRect)

        pygame.display.update()

        send_data(fata)

        send_data(spate)

        send_data(stanga)

        send_data(dreapta)


receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()

write_thread = threading.Thread(target=write)
write_thread.start()
```

P.S: "dreapta","stanga","fata","spate" are just indications (translated they will be "right","left","front","back", in this order)

Any Ideeas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in way or another
I just added the FUNTION (like the "()") to the write threadding and since i wont need to receive i deleted thereceive threadding

Final code:

```
import threading
import socket
import pygame
pygame.init()

green = (0, 255, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)

font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)

win = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 500))

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("127.0.0.1", 55555))

def send_data(string, data):
    if data == True:
        client.send(f"{str(string)}1".encode('utf-8'))
    elif data == False:
        client.send(f"{str(string)}0".encode('utf-8'))

def receive():
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            print(message)
        except:
            print("An error occured!")
            client.close()
            exit()

def write():
    running = True
    fata = False
    spate = False
    stanga = False
    dreapta = False
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                client.close()
                running = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    fata = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    spate = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    stanga = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    dreapta = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    fata = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    spate = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    stanga = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    dreapta = False

        win.fill(black)

        textw = font.render("fata:", True, green)
        textRect = textw.get_rect(center=(40, 20))
        win.blit(textw, textRect)

        textw = font.render(str(fata), True, green)
        textRect = textw.get_rect(center=(125, 20))
        win.blit(textw, textRect)

        texts = font.render("spate:", True, green)
        textRect = texts.get_rect(center=(55, 50))
        win.blit(texts, textRect)

        texts = font.render(str(spate), True, green)
        textRect = texts.get_rect(center=(150, 50))
        win.blit(texts, textRect)

        texta = font.render("stanga:", True, green)
        textRect = texta.get_rect(center=(65, 80))
        win.blit(texta, textRect)

        texta = font.render(str(stanga), True, green)
        textRect = texta.get_rect(center=(170, 80))
        win.blit(texta, textRect)

        textd = font.render("dreapta:", True, green)
        textRect = textd.get_rect(center=(70, 110))
        win.blit(textd, textRect)

        textd = font.render(str(dreapta), True, green)
        textRect = textd.get_rect(center=(180, 110))
        win.blit(textd, textRect)

        pygame.display.update()

        send_data("fata", fata)
        send_data("spate", spate)
        send_data("stanga", stanga)
        send_data("dreapta", dreapta)


write_thread = threading.Thread(target=write())
write_thread.start()
```